# AWS send http request through elastic load balancer

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I am a beginner and trying to send `http request`s through elastic load balancer. Could anybody explain briefly about the steps that I need?

- set up **Elastic Load Balancer A**
- get DNS of the **Elastic Load Balancer A**
- register `EC2` instances to the **Elastic Load Balancer A**
- send traffic to the `DNS` of **Elastic Load Balancer A**

But I have no idea what kind of configuration or set up I need to put in the `EC2` instances that are to be attached to this **Elastic Load Balancer A**. Do I need to set up `Listener`? If so, how do I set this?

I just want to send `http request` under the ip of `EC2`s and **Elastic Load Balancer A** so that I get different IPs assigned to each requests.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Amazon EC2 instances behind an Elastic Load Balancer serve traffic on **port 80** (HTTP). When creating the Load Balancer, you can configure which ports should receive traffic (80, 442, 1024+).

Think of it this way... The Load Balancer simply sits "in front" of the EC2 instances. If a user was to go directly to your EC2 instance directly (eg enter its IP Address in a web browser), they should see a website. Going to the Load Balancer does the same thing, but it distributes the requests amongst multiple EC2 instances.

So, in most cases, it's just a matter of running a web server or app on your EC2 instance running on port 80.